# Append div in canvas and create DataURL not working

Tags: html, angularjs, canvas, ionic-framework, todataurl

I have require to show a image and above this image i have require to place 2 divs, one div containing image and another div contain text,and require to combined all this three to create a final image and store this final image in database/server, I am using canvas to achieve this and my project is in Ionic/AngularJS, I am not able to use img and text directly without div, because i have also require to drag-drop and resize this img and text as well, and this is not achieving without using div.

**This is my html code.**

```
<div class="item item-image" ng-repeat="picture in product.images" id="mainwall">
     <img ng-src="{{wallMainImage}}" ng-init="setInitSrc(picture.src)" width="330" height="400" crossOrigin="Anonymous" id="preview1" class="wall-image"/>
     <div id="wall-design" draggable style="position: absolute;">
        <img ng-src="{{walldesign}}" />
     </div>
     <div id="wall-text" draggable>
        <p>{{wallText}}</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

and i have canvas element define at the last as

```
<canvas id="tempCanvas" style="position: relative;"></canvas>
```

and in controller on saving button click, I am calling a function which have below contents.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('tempCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');    
var source =  document.getElementById("preview1");
var width = source.naturalWidth; 
var height = source.naturalHeight; 
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;              
var canvasDiv = document.getElementById('wall-design');
canvas.appendChild(canvasDiv);
console.log("canvas", canvas)
context.drawImage(source,0,0, width, height);    
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
$timeout( function(){
   $scope.wallMainImage = dataURL;
   if ($scope.$root.$$phase != '$apply' && $scope.$root.$$phase != '$digest') {
       $scope.$apply();
   }
}, 200);
```

**I am getting a exact canvas console which i want as shown below**

```
<canvas id="tempCanvas" style="position: relative;" width="700" height="519">
   <div id="wall-design" draggable="" style="position: absolute; height: 153px; width: 54px; left: 128px; top: 105px;" class="ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-resizable">
        <img ng-src="images/designs/3.jpg" src="images/designs/3.jpg">
        <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
        <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
        <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
   </div></canvas>
```

and I am also getting a datURL which is very long in a encoded letters and  at last i am getting a image which have only starting image only and other image which require to shown above this image not shown

please inform me.. where i am doing wrong

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You can't append anything in a canvas element, you can just draw on it. There are libraries out there that will parse the html and convert it to canvas drawings, the most famous one being html2canvas.

Comment: hi @ Kaiido, I have check html2canvas and found, it is used to take "screenshots" of webpages, but this is not my requirement, as we can drawImage or fillText using context of a canvas, I just want similar thing, which can append div on canvas, please suggest something

Comment: Read carefully the project's homepage, it doesn't take screenshots, but parses the html and draws it using canvas methods. You can't draw html elements with drawImage, only visual media. The only highly limited other way would be to append your html in an svg (external resources need to be encoded to dataURI) and draw this svg. But this is really hacky, not stable at all, will make most browsers taint your canvas and, well, not a good idea. So stick with what exists, simply call html2Canvas on your container and you're good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I am giving the solution, which works in my case

```
html2canvas(angular.element('#wallimageid'), {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
         var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
         console.log("img", img);
         $scope.savedGalleryImage = img;
      }, 
      useCORS:true
})
```

I am using angularjs directive, if anyone want to do this using jquery, simply replace angular.element with $

I have use useCORS to use image src which are not available in our local storage instead coming from some site.

user also need to download html2canvas, i have download this by taken git clone using this command

```
git clone --recursive git://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas.git
```

and specify in html file by

```
<script src="js/lib/html2canvas/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
```

here use your own path

Thanks

Comment: `useCORS: true` Could not upvote this enough!!! I had a PDF loading without the images even though CORS was enabled and the canvas wan't tainted. All bcoz this flag was missing.